# Answer A is the same with answer B, answer B has references. Would answer A be considered to have references?

Tags: discussion, answers, references, hyperlinks

Let's see [this non-reference answer](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/151/99). It is agreed to be a good answer, but since it doesn't contain any reference, there is a comment below encourages the answerer to add.

However, since there is another one has references, would this answer still need references?

There is a logic behind this: answer A is basically the same with answer B, answer B has references, therefore answer A already has reference. The answerer of answer A doesn't need to declare that "this answer is basically the same with answer B", the readers will see that logic for themselves.

I know that if we look at the date, this answer came first. At that time, it should have references. But after the answer with references came out, that logic appeared and I think there is no need to ask it reference (and that remind comment too).

I think this will raise another issue. If answer A is basically the same with answer B, but this time this one is from **another question**, and if there is a link to it, would the answer A be consider to have references?